# Do I have to dual-boot or can I do a fresh install?

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, uefi

This question is probably ridiculously stupid but I have a Windows 8 machine (new one with the UEFI thing).

I'm going to be installing Ubuntu later, and I was wondering if I absolutely have to dual-boot it with Windows 8 or if I can wipe the Windows installation and install just Ubuntu?

Comment: what is that you want to know, it all depends on your needs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: @KasiyA Not a duplicate, I'm asking if I should dual boot or not. I've installed Ubuntu before, I'm not new to it, just on this system I am.

Comment: If you want to keep your Windows so you can install Ubuntu as a dual boot system with Win. NO if you don't want your Windows OS then you can wipe it and install a fresh Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it, and ended up dual booting.

It worked just like it did when I used to install it. Installed fine and without a hitch. Set aside some memory on a separate partition and installed it on there.

Ran fine, ran into a little Wireless Networking bug but that was fixed easily.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to dual boot.  Ubuntu will be just fine by itself even with UEFI, you just have to keep/create a UEFI boot partition when you install it by itself.

Answer (score -2):

remember when dual booting on the same hard drive you risk corrupting mbr and boot sectors Id recommend installing linux on a separate drive and keeping windows some times you need windows files for certain things if you have the room and an extra drive I'd definitely dual boot.

Comment: Im currently running win7 and ubuntustudio64 good set up for gaming and business

Comment: I have multiple partitions, but no separate hard drives. It's just a laptop.

Comment: my laptop has 2 hard drive bays

Comment: So should I dual boot?

Comment: So why did I get down voted on my answer was it not relevant?